# Confusion on instance variable as opposed to lack of it

Tags: ruby

Came across this code from 'The Grounded Rubyist'

```
module Stacklike
  def stack
    @stack ||=[]
  end 

  def add_to_stack(obj)
    stack.push(obj)
  end

  def take_from_stack
    stack.pop
  end
end
```

as opposed to:

```
class Stack

 attr_reader :stack

 def initialize
  @stack = [] 
 end 

 def add_to_stack(obj)
  @stack.push(obj)
 end

 def take_from_stack
  @stack.pop
 end
end
```

My primary confusion stems from the fact that in the module, the instance variable `@stack` is not in `add_to_stack` and `take_from_stack` methods. How is the state of the `stack` tracked otherwise?

In the class, `@stack` is used in all methods which is the norm I'm used to.

Can someone explain how this works in the module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in the module, the instance variable @stack is not in add_to_stack and
>   take_from_stack methods. How is the state of the stack tracked
>   otherwise?

Not quite. `add_to_stack` pushes something on `@stack`, because the `stack` method returns `@stack`:

```
  def stack
    @stack ||=[]
  end

  def add_to_stack(obj)
    stack.push(obj)
  end
```

So in the end, @stack *is used* in `add_to_stack`.

Note that you could safely remove the `@`s from all `@stack` in `class Stack` (except the assignment in `initialize`), because `attr_reader :stack` defines a `stack` method that returns `@stack`.

Comment: oh! light bulb finally. i confused `stack` to be the instance variable `@stack`, when it was talking about the method! Thank you! Also thank you for the addendum!

Comment: will accept your answer later as it's saying in four minutes, and i gotta go. but thank you again!

Comment: You can't remove from all. You can't remove from `initialize`.

Comment: @sawa, um, sorry, not sure what you mean?

Comment: @sawa, oh, got what you meant! you meant his addendum!